# Update previous line instead print new line

Tags: c, printf

Here is a simple program in c. It take two integers and add them. In this code, I want to update previous line by new line instead making a new one, Can any body help me on this topic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int a,b;
printf("Enter two integer to add\r");
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
a=a+b;
printf("Your value is -- %d",a);

return 0;
}
```

I have use \r instead of \n, to take cursor back to the start. I have input data in program console which writing from start. But the next line "Your value is.."  printed as new line, I want to remove the first line and then input value and print next line "Your value..". How do I do that? Please help me

Comment: Short answer: you can't (very easily). Long answer: What you want is not part of the standard C language or runtime. Something like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) is one alternative, but frankly would be like driving thumbtacks with a sledge hammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot move up in the terminal like that, unless using some complex lib as curses.
You can use the "clear screen" trick, maybe that would achieve what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
    int a,b;
    system("clear"); // or "cls" on windows
    printf("Enter two integer to add\r");
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    system("clear"); // or "cls" on windows
    a=a+b;
    printf("Your value is -- %d",a);

    return 0;
    }
```